# AngularJS: ng-bind-html doesn't work with button tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having problem to print out an input type button dynamically in a div "ng-bind-html".

HTML template:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="add()">
<div ng-bind-html="snippet"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.add = function() {
   $scope.snippet = "<input type='button' value='Test' ng-click='myFunc()'><b>Test 2</b>";
}
```

The tag input is removed and then I see just the "bold" text Test 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For some reason your html tag is mark as `unsafe` by angular js. If you sure that your snippet text is safe, you can `$sce.trustAsHtml` it before adding it to the `$scope.snippet`.

```
app.controller('yourCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.add = function(){
        var text = "<input type='button' value='Test'><b>Test 2</b>";

        // mark it as clean
        text = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);

        $scope.snippet = text;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: It worked but the ng-click in the input button added doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.
Suddenly there's `ng-click`? Now, use `$compile`, Thanks.

Comment: Iqbal Fauzi, would you please explain how to use $complie in this scenario, I tried and not able to understand

Comment: me 2... I was unable to use compile... it either generated an object unusable by ng-bind-html or i came back to square one and lost the ng-click