# how can i use ng-click in ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I am using ng-bind-html in my controller like

```
$scope.message='  You  currently have no ORDERS <a href= "javascript:void(0)" ng-click="Back()">Back13</a>';
```

and in html page

```
<strong ng-bind-html="message">Warning!</strong>
```

But the Back() is not working even i tried the $compile as [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889376/ng-click-dont-work-with-ng-bind-html)  .
Can any one solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$scope.message='  You  currently have no ORDERS <a **href="javascript:;"** ng-click="Back()">Back13</a>';
```

Change `href="javascript:void(0)"`  to `href="javascript:;"`

and also see this below discussions

[ng-click do not work when a template bound using ng-bind-html-unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096239/ng-click-do-not-work-when-a-template-bound-using-ng-bind-html-unsafe)

[AngularJS: ng-bind-html doesn't work with button tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744372/angularjs-ng-bind-html-doesnt-work-with-button-tag)

Comment: Thank you @user256103 for your response,but your suggestions are not working for me ,just now i have updated the code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bpvGd5VhRj5IfvVc94ZW?p=preview) ,if possible change the plnkr to solve the problem.